# Step question about differential equation $x^2y''+\alpha xy'+\beta y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Euler Equation:
$$x^2 y''+\alpha xy'+\beta y=0,  \quad x=e^t$$

why $$\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left( \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)=
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left( \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)\left( \frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\right) \text ?$$

Why are they equal and why we need this transform?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You should TeX the entire equation. Your symbols can't be viewed on all devices.

Comment: You need that transform in order to change the variable and the equation into a constant coefficients differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have the following change of variable
$$x=e^t \implies t=\ln x$$
So that appluing the product rule gives:
$$y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}\dfrac{1}{x}=e^{-t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$$
Do the same for $y''$

We use this change of variable in order to transform the original DE into a constant coefficients second order linear differential equation that is easy to integrate.

Comment: Thank you so much！

Comment: you're welcome @ashids